# Responsive organizational chart from CSS3 Family Tree

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

Im using **CSS3 Family Tree** and **Bootstrap 3** but it is not responsive.

[For Desktop resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvL8j.png) 
[For Mobile or lower resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTFz8.png)
Here's the Fiddle code taken from **[DEMO](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)** so you can check the problem about responsive
thanks

Comment: Hi Kapitan, Are you able to make this CSS3 Family tree responsive?

Comment: Not yet. Actually I didn't use that instead I used the simple ones like bootstrap. But if have a way to make this responsive you can answer this question so we can help the others who are struggle with this issue.

Comment: Sure Kapitan. Mean while is it possible for you to share your Bootstrap code for this Family Tree, that would be also be helpful for me, I am no way  restricted to this CSS3 solution only. Bootstrap solution is also fine for me.

Comment: Did either of you come up with a responsive family tree that could be shared?